# Python. Проблема с загрузкой словаря из JSON

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram, бот

У меня есть телеграмм бот, данные о пользователях я храню в JSON. У меня есть отдельный файл для выгрузки и загрузки данных.
Вот он:

```python
import json
import logging

all_records, saved_contacts = {}, {}

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


async def upload_data(self):
    with open("tg_bot/misc/data/all_records.json", "w", encoding="utf-8-sig") as file:
        logger.info(f"all_records = {all_records}")
        json.dump(all_records, file, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)

    with open("tg_bot/misc/data/saved_contacts.json", "w", encoding="utf-8-sig") as file:
        logger.info(f"saved_contacts = {saved_contacts}")
        json.dump(saved_contacts, file, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)

    logger.info("Data has been successfully uploaded!")


async def load_data(self):
    with open("tg_bot/misc/data/all_records.json", "r", encoding="utf-8-sig") as file:
        all_records = json.load(file)

    with open("tg_bot/misc/data/saved_contacts.json", encoding="utf-8-sig") as file:
        saved_contacts = json.load(file)

    logger.info(f"all_records = {all_records}")
    logger.info(f"saved_contacts = {saved_contacts}")

    logger.info("Data has been successfully loaded!")
```

`load_data()` выполняю при запуске, `upload_data()` при отключении телеграмм бота.

```
executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True, on_startup=load_data, on_shutdown=upload_data)
```

С выгрузкой проблем нету, а с загрузкой интересная для меня ситуация. Я вывожу два словаря в консоль в функции и в handler. В функции все нормально, вот:

```
data_handling.py:28 #INFO     [2023-04-27 13:41:00,218] - tg_bot.misc.data_handling - all_records = {'1643710214': {'1': {'service': ...
data_handling.py:29 #INFO     [2023-04-27 13:41:00,218] - tg_bot.misc.data_handling - saved_contacts = {'1643710214': {'1': {'name': 'lored', 'number': '1654613'}}
}
```

Но когда прописываю команду **/start** и опять хочу посмотреть содержимое, то вижу 2 пустых словаря:

```
filling_form.py:28 #INFO     [2023-04-27 13:43:36,301] - tg_bot.handlers.filling_form - all_records = {}
filling_form.py:29 #INFO     [2023-04-27 13:43:36,301] - tg_bot.handlers.filling_form - saved_contacts = {}
```

Словари импортирую из **data_handling.py**

Помогите, пожалуйста!

Comment: А почему у вас функции асинхронные?

Comment: all_records.update(json.load(file))

Comment: Функции асинхронные из-за start_polling, он в аргументы хочет принимать только асинхронные

Comment: Без async ошибку выбивает

Comment: Спасибо! помогло